CFG to CNF conversion, What to do if start symbol is non-Generative
S -> ASB
A -> aA | a
B -> b

On this cfg S is the start symbol and it is non-generative. I have no idea what to do on the step of removing non-generative non terminals
I looked some converter sites and they seem to don't remove non-generative non terminals

This question is better suited for cs.stackexchange

My guess is that the production for S is missing | epsilon.
